# Python: Get the lowest, most frequent value of a list

Tags: python, frequency, minimum

*Hi Community!
Could You please help me regarding following issue? I do not manage do achieve an efficient solution for my problem. Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks to all of You in advance!*

**My Problem**: As *first step*, I would like to identify the most frequent value(s) of a given list of integers. As *second step*, if there are multiple most frequent values, I would like to take the lowest among them.

**Example**: Given following list, I would like to receive the "**5**", as it is the lowest, most frequent value.

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,8,8,8]
```

*Could You please help me? Thanks!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [24]: list = [1,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,8,8,8]
    ...:

In [25]: max(sorted(set(list)), key=list.count)
Out[25]: 5
```

Comment: Wow that was fast! Thank You so much for Your help - will accept Your answer ASAP. :-)

Comment: How does this guarantee that the lowest mode will be chosen?

Comment: @SayandipDutta `If multiple items are maximal, the function returns the first one encountered.` - `max` function in https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max

Comment: True, but how do you know the order is maintained in the set`?

Comment: I think @SayandipDutta is correct, for example:
`l = [1, 100000];
print(max(set(l), key=l.count))`
prints 100000

Comment: You will have to sort the list, in case it's not sorted

Comment: @bigbounty, I think it's supposed to be `sorted(set(list))` instead of `set(sorted(list))` as set does not guarantee the order.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to get the most common value out of multiple candidates in linear time using the built-in [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class:

```
from collections import Counter

l = [1,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,8,8,8]
counter = Counter(l)
_, top_freq = counter.most_common(1)[0]
lower_most_common = min(key for key, freq in counter.items() if freq == top_freq)
```